# Is it possible to run multiple containers on Docker to run a common service?

Tags: docker, containers, lamp

I'm very new with Docker, and the most trouble I had with it, was to:

- Try to make my own image with basic LAMP (phpMyAdmin included)
- Using already created LAMP images ([This one works for me but I'm having troubles with phpMyAdmin and privileges](https://github.com/fauria/docker-lamp))

So I was asking myself if it would be possible to run multiple containers that connect between them (I saw there's the possibility to create a network on Docker but I don't know its limitations) and run as a single service like LAMP. In other words:

1. Apache2 + PHP -> **connected with container nº2** || Host connected through port forwarding.
2. MySQL + PhpMyAdmin -> **connected with container nº1**

I'm still very confused by all the stuff you can or can't do with Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) - it allows to run many containers by one command: `docker-compose up`.

You need to configure them, i.e. something like this: https://github.com/pnglabz/docker-compose-lamp.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by putting the containers in the same network.

On the host (containing the database):

```
# docker-compose.yml
    services:
      db:
        mediawiki_db:
          image: mariadb
          networks:
            - mediawiki
          ports:
            - 3306:3306
    networks:
      mediawiki:
        driver: bridge
```

On the client (container with phpmyadmin):

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - db_mediawiki

networks:
  db_mediawiki:
    external: true
```

On the phpMyAdmin page under server, fill in the IP of the db container.

Also make sure you have granted external access privileges to your mysql user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
    IDENTIFIED BY 'password' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```